# Getting undefined value, when trying to read the date value from an input field

Tags: java, jquery

This is my UI:

[image]

My js file for date picker function:

```
$( function() {
    $( "#reportDateFrom" ).datepicker({ dateFormat : 'dd-M-yy' });
} );
$( function() {
    $( "#reportDateTo" ).datepicker({ dateFormat : 'dd-M-yy' });
} );
```

This is my html page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/KGDLC_Report/resources/js/page- 
scripts/userWiseReportKGDLC.js"></script>
<div id="body">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>KGDLC Report</legend>
            <div id="box">
                <form  th:object="${posTable}" method="GET" >
                <p>
                    <label>Date From</label>
                    <input  type="text" id="reportDateFrom" /> 
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label>Date To</label>
                    <input  type="text" id="reportDateTo" /> 
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label>POS ID</label>
                    <select id="posId" th:field="*{posId}" >
                                <option value="">--</option>
                                <option th:each="pos : ${posIdList}"
                                th:value="${pos}"
                                th:utext="${pos}" />
                    </select>
                </p>
                <p> 
                <label>Report type</label>
                <select name="reportType" id="reportType">
                                <option value="pdf">PDF</option>
                                <option value="csv">CSV</option>
                                <option value="xls">XLS</option>
                                <option value="doc">DOC</option>
                </select>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <input class="formbutton" type="button" 
  onclick="reportPrintKGDLC()" value="View"/>
                </p>        
                </form>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
```

After clicking `view` button, `reportPrintKGDLC()` method inside `userWiseReportKGDLC.js` file is working.

My `userWiseReportKGDLC.js` file:

```
function reportPrintKGDLC() {
alert("inside js : reportPrintKGDLC()");
var outputFormat = $('#reportType').val();
var dateFrom = $('#reportDateFrom').val();
var dateTo = $('#reportDateTo').val();
var posId = $('#posId').val();

alert(outputFormat);
alert('dateFrom');
alert('dateTo');
alert(posId);

var myWindow = window.open("Print Preview.");
var html = "<div><h3>View</h3>" +
        "<iframe id='ifrmrptSummary' width='100%' height='100%'></iframe>" +
        "</div>";
var scriptCode = "myWindow<script type='text/javascript'>"+              
  " 
  document.getElementById('ifrmrptSummary').src= 
    '/KGDLC_Report/main/userWiseRepo          rtKGDLC? 
 dateFrom="+dateFrom+"&dateTo="+dateTo
     +"&outputFormat="+outputFormat+"&posId="+posId+"'</script>";
 myWindow.document.write("<html><head></head><body>" + html + scriptCode+ " 
 </body></html>");

};
```

Then I am trying to read values sent from `userWiseReportKGDLC.js` file to my java file where I will print reprot.

```
@RequestMapping("/userWiseReportKGDLC")
public void viewReport(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse 
response) {
    System.out.println("/userWiseReportKGDCL");
    String dateFrom = request.getParameter("dateFrom");
    String dateTo = request.getParameter("dateTo");
    String outputFormat = request.getParameter("outputFormat");
    String posId = request.getParameter("posId");

    System.out.println("dateFrom: " + dateFrom);
    System.out.println("dateTo: "+dateTo);
    System.out.println("Output Format: " + outputFormat);
    System.out.println("posId: "+posId);

    Map<String,Object> param = new HashMap<String,Object>();
    param.put("dateFrom", dateFrom);
    param.put("dateTo", dateTo);
    param.put("posId", posId);

    String path = 

    request.getSession().getServletContext() 
   .getRealPath("/resources/jasper/POS_Report.jrxml");
    System.out.println(path);
    reportService.generateReport(path, outputFormat, param, response);
    System.out.println("After calling reportService.generateReport()");
}
```

I am getting exact value for `outputFormat` & `posId` values from js file. But getting  `undefined` value  for `dateFrom` & `dateTo` field. Don't understand why. Need help.

Comment: Your date format in js file should be `dd-MM-yy`

Comment: I have changed value to `dd-MM-yy` but still 'undefined'

Comment: Please post actual code and not images of code. It makes it impossible to copy to answers and is not searchable. See [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question) for other reasons also

Comment: What do you see when you log the datepicker input values in browser console? What is actually being put into the url for iframe?

Comment: @ charlietfl , edited as code format. Now help pls! 
nothing showing in browser console.